# TSQL only group a column when a condition is met in another column

Tags: t-sql, having

The result of this query has multiple transactionCodes. I want to group  the transactionCodes only if applyToLineID = '0'. In other words, if the applyToLineID is something other than 0, the transaction codes should not be grouped. I think this can be done with HAVING statement, but I could not get it to work. Below you will find 2 pieces of code, the first piece is my original code, and the 2nd piece is the original code plus my attempt to perform the aforementioned grouping.

Original Code:

```
SELECT 
ar.arlineitemid,
ar.siteid,
ar.transactioncode,
ar.description,
ar.amount,
ar.balance,
ar.applytolineid,
ar.posteddate,
TC.transactioncode,
TC.arlineitemid

FROM tswdata.dbo.t_arlineitem as AR     

left JOIN

(
SELECT

ar2.transactioncode,
ar2.arlineitemid

FROM tswdata.dbo.t_arlineitem as ar2    

WHERE  

ar2.SiteID = '101'
AND
(AR2.Transactioncode LIKE 'A%'  And
AR2.Transactioncode NOT LIKE 'AS%' And
AR2.Transactioncode NOT LIKE 'AF%' And
AR2.Transactioncode NOT LIKE 'AX%')
) TC

ON
ar.applytolineid = TC.arlineitemid

WHERE  

ar.SiteID = '101'
AND
AR.Transactioncode <> 'A18'
```

Code where I tried to perform the conditional grouping:

```
SELECT 
ar.arlineitemid,
ar.siteid,
ar.transactioncode,
ar.description,
ar.amount,
ar.balance,
ar.applytolineid,
ar.posteddate,
TC.transactioncode,
TC.arlineitemid

FROM tswdata.dbo.t_arlineitem as AR     

left JOIN

(
SELECT

ar2.transactioncode,
ar2.arlineitemid

FROM tswdata.dbo.t_arlineitem as ar2    

WHERE  

ar2.SiteID = '101'
AND
(AR2.Transactioncode LIKE 'A%'  And
AR2.Transactioncode NOT LIKE 'AS%' And
AR2.Transactioncode NOT LIKE 'AF%' And
AR2.Transactioncode NOT LIKE 'AX%')
) TC

ON
ar.applytolineid = TC.arlineitemid

WHERE  

ar.SiteID = '101'
AND
AR.Transactioncode <> 'A18'

GROUP BY 
ar.transactioncode,

HAVING
ar.ApplyTolineId = '0'
```

Comment: Can you provide a example set of data, and the intended result you want?

Comment: I'm assuming your grouped query doesn't even run...you haven't used aggregate functions on any of the columns in your SELECT clause, and the HAVING clause doesn't reference a field from the GROUP BY clause or an aggregate function.

Comment: EVERY column needs to be in the group by or an aggregate.  Having clause needs to be an aggregate.  Question is not clear to me.

Comment: A fair clarification, @Paparazzi!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could union two queries: one that includes everything except items where the transaction code is 0, and another that only has the aggregate of the items where the transaction code is 0.

Comment: How do you go about combining aggregates with non aggregates?

Comment: As long as the two queries return the same number of fields of the same types in the same order, you can union them.

Comment: That is two ifs.   What is the chance of them both being true?

Comment: Presumably the OP has the wit and wisdom to decide what columns to have and make it so.  One could always populate nulls in the aggregated set where there is no natural choice for an aggregation function.  "description" and "balance" come to mind as fields in the original query that won't necessarily work in an aggregation.

Comment: Not even a logical question.  I think you presume to much regarding wit and wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

Consider breaking down your problem like this:

You have two sets of data you want to look at - the ones where `applyToLineID = '0'`, and the ones where `applyToLineID <> '0'`.

You have a query that pulls out the raw information that both sets would use to evaluate the `applyToLineID` logic.

Your solution for this will probably look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (select common data, Grouped Values from (common_query) where applyToLineID = 0)
UNION
SELECT * FROM
    (select common data, unGrouped Values from (common_query) where applyToLineID <> 0)
```